# Three.js - noise animation just from THREE.FilmPass()

Tags: javascript, three.js

In my Learning Three.js book [Chapter Eleven 02-post-processing-simple-passes.html](https://github.com/josdirksen/learning-threejs/blob/master/chapter-11/02-post-processing-simple-passes.html#L98), the author was able to make a noise animation from `var effectFilm = new THREE.FilmPass(0.8, 0.325, 256, false);`

[In the book's code example](https://github.com/josdirksen/learning-threejs/blob/master/chapter-11/02-post-processing-simple-passes.html#L98) the orbiting is not causing the noise effect, because when I remove the orbit animation, the noise animation is still there. 
It's not coming from the textures, because when I remove them, the noise effect is still there.

I'm dieing to figure out how this was done just from using `THREE.FilmPass()`.

I've tried using THREE.FilmPass() in my own experiment and I can not make the noise effect. Instead, I just get the normal scan line effect without the noise.

What I am doing different is: 1) I am using a 2d geometry instead of 3d geometry, 2) not using 2 cameras 3) not using directional lights, 4) not reusing my geometry with THREE.CopyShader, 5) not using orbiting.

```
 function init() {

    var stats = initStats();

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-window.innerWidth, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, -window.innerHeight, -10000, 10000);

    scene.add(camera);

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

    renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0xEEEEEE, 1.0));
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;

    var coupleTexture =  THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('./sina1.jpg');

    var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1);
    var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: coupleTexture,
                                                    depthTest: false });
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
    plane.scale.set(1000, 1000, 1, 1);
           scene.add(plane);

    document.getElementById("WebGL-output").appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    var renderPass = new THREE.RenderPass(scene, camera);
    var effectFilm = new THREE.FilmPass(0.8, 0.325, 256, false);
    effectFilm.renderToScreen = true;

    var composer = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer);
    composer.addPass(renderPass);
    composer.addPass(effectFilm);



    render();

    function render() {
        stats.update();
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        composer.render(scene, camera);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great question! I opened up the tutorial file and basically eliminated and replaced things until I got to about your stage. Noise generation depends on time, and one last thing you changed is how you render the scene! Try replacing `composer.render(scene, camera);` with

```
var delta = clock.getDelta();
composer.render(delta);
```

while adding `var clock = new THREE.Clock();` to your init function.

Comment: For learning purposes.... before I was doing `composer.render(scene, camera)`. When I changed it to `composer.render(delta)` the scene was still rendered. Was this because of `var renderPass = new THREE.RenderPass(scene, camera);`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The RenderPass handles the rendering portion inside of the EffectComposer, then passes the rendered result to FilmPass (notice the ordering of how you add passes matters). Also, it's worthwhile looking at the source code for [EffectComposer](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js). The only argument that `render()` accepts is `delta`. Hope this helps!